# ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'absl' (unknown location)

Tags: tensorflow

When I import the TensorFlow package, I got a error:ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'absl' (unknown location).
The version numbers for Python and TensorFlow are as follows:
python       3.9.18
TensorFlow   2.15.1
Can anyone help me answer this? Thanks...

I hope anyone can help me answer this error